# Regular subgroups of affine general linear groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $AGL(2d,2)$ be the affine general linear group acting natrually on a $2d$-dimensional vector space over $GF(2)$. Is there a regular subgroup of $AGL(2d,2)$ isomorphic to $Z_{2^d}:Z_{2^d}$ for $d=3$ and $4$ respectively?

I tried to compute all regular subgroups of a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $AGL(2d,2)$ using the magma command "RegularSubgroups" but failed since it's too memory-consuming.

Comment: As a computational problem, I think this is very hard. I have some interest in this, because I (and a few other others) are trying to use Magma to compute the regular subgroups of ${\rm ASp}(8,2)$. We expect to succeed eventually, but it will involve a huge amount of computer time and memory. My guess is that this computation would be possible, but difficult, for ${\rm AGL}(6,2)$ and impossible for ${\rm AGL}(8,2)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I hope to compute the problem for AGL(8,2) and I think the only possibility to succed on my laptop is utilizing the specified structure $Z_8{:}Z_8$ rather than constructing all the regular subgroups of the Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$ directly. I am able to construct all the semiregular cyclic subgroups of order $8$ in $P$, but failed in searching regular subgroups $Z_8{:}Z_8$ in their normalisers because of lack of memory.

Comment: By the way, why were you trying to calculate the regular subgroups of a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ rather than of $G$ itself? There will be far fewer conjugacy classes of subgroups in $G$, so it is quicker to do it in $G$. Try it with ${\rm AGL}(5,2)$ with $G$ and with a Sylow 2-subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt If nothing is wrong, the codes in the next comment for magma prove there does not exist regular subgroup $Z_8{:}Z_8$ in $AGL(6,2)$. My laptop runs about 15 minutes. But if I substitue P for G in the definition of S, then it will run out of memory. (The available memory of my laptop is no more than 2G.)

Comment: G:=AGL(6,2);
G;
P:=Sylow(G,2);
S:=[a:a in CyclicSubgroups(P:OrderEqual:=8)|IsSemiregular(a`subgroup) eq true];
#S;
num:=0;
for x in S do
 N:=Normaliser(P,x`subgroup);
 for y in [a:a in CyclicSubgroups(N:OrderEqual:=8)|IsSemiregular(a`subgroup) eq true] do
  if #(x`subgroup meet y`subgroup) eq 1 then
   H:=sub<N|x`subgroup,y`subgroup>;
   if IsSemiregular(H) eq true then
    H;
   end if;
  end if;
 end for;
 num:=num+1;
 num;
end for;

Comment: I tried it with $G$ in place of $S$. It was a little slower and used about 180MB, but resulted in $|S|=4$. The best choice was the subgroup of index 63 in $G$. That took only a couple of seconds and gave $|S|=7$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is it because my version of magma v2.12-16 is too old? Did you tried to construct all the conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroup of order $8$ in $AGL(8,2)$?